# Android how to make toolbar like twitter 2.0 for android

Tags: android

Can some one give me idea how to make toolbar like on twitter 2.0 , see picture. Is there some component like this or tab or something other?

thanks

[image: twitter 2.0 toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

and if your SDK isn't at that level you can follow these steps:

http://sacoinvest.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-build-dashboard-user-interface.html

Comment: action bar appears in android honeycomb (on tablets). Dashboard is another gui element

Comment: For pre-honeycomb you need to build the actionbar yourself. Its pretty easy (src code in the second link)

Comment: In the second link I see example to build dashboard. It's another gui element. Toolbar in the twitter 2.0 realize a tabBar functionality.

Comment: There is also code in the example for the toolbar. Its mostly in the .xml files though there are some class bits too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to you simple LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and four ToggleButtons inside.
like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ToggleButton
    …
/>
<ToggleButton
    …
/>
<ToggleButton
    …
/>
<ToggleButton
    …
/></LinearLayout>
```

And if you want a tab functionality like in twitter app, see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes I like tab functionality, you think twitter app use custom TabHost for this ? thanks

Comment: I don't know what twitter 2.0 using. But this functionality similar to TabHost.